# Want to bold few characters of a word get bold in treenode in winforms using c#

Tags: c#, treeview

i have "search TextBox" to search in treeview, i give result very well. But i want to get those parts get Bold which i typed in "search TextBox" of my winform.

Ex: i Typed Ram then it gives **Ram**esh .

Comment: You would need to manually do this I would imagine.  Your question is not exactly clear.  Please attempt to revise the question so statements like "which i typed in "search TextBox" of my winform" are clear to somebody that has no idea what your form looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TreeNode class doesn't support that, its Text is always drawn with one font, the TreeView.Font.  Making parts of the text bold is technically possible but very hard to get right.  You need to enable custom drawing with the TreeView.DrawMode property and DrawItem event, there's a good example of it in the MSDN Library article.

That's the easy part, the hard problem is that the node is too small to fit the text after you draw parts of it in a bold font.  TreeView is missing a "MeasureNodeText" event that would allow you to ask for enough space.  The only workaround for that is to lie about the node text and make it artificially wider by prefixing characters.  Which you then don't draw in the DrawItem event.  Very hard to get consistently right, you'll want to consider a fixed pitch font instead.

I cannot recommend you pursue this unless the feature is really important to you.  This otherwise explains why you never see this feature in other programs.  Consider changing the color instead of the font weight too.  Still hard to glue the pieces together btw.

Comment: It might be less effort to port your app to WPF :)

Comment: @by doing `node.Text = node.Text` I could workaround the problem with missing text after changing `TreeNode.Font`