# Change the part of the node text to be bold of TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms

I know I can change Node Font property to change text formatting but how can I change part of the text shown in node to bold like 'abcd**abcd**'

Comment: You have to do it yourself.  See DrawMode and the DrawItem event.

Comment: Here is exactly the same question as you've asked: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776185/want-to-bold-few-characters-of-a-word-get-bold-in-treenode-in-winforms-using-c-s)

Comment: thanks katia, i could'nt found it :)